# stop a program when a key is pressed emu8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I've been trying to find information about this but I didn´t find anything useful anywhere.
My problem is that I need to pause a program in emu8086 whenever the letter S is pressed on the keyboard and start it again right where it was paused if I press the same key again. I don´t know any interruption or instruction in emu8086 that could be running background in my program just waiting for a key to be pressed.

I have been searching information about this everywhere, but I couldn´t find anything in assembly language. If any of you could help me with that, it would be great so I could finish my project.

Comment: In your loop you can use BIOS [Int 16h/AH=1](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1755.htm) to check if a key has been pressed and if there has been one pressed then you can use BIOS [Int 16/Ah=0](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm) to retrieve that character and then compare it with `S`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@MichaelPetch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857942/michael-petch) said you can use [int 16h/AH=1](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0230.HTM).

Here is a sample code:

```
read:

mov ah, 1 
int 16h 

cmp al, 'S'          
jne read
```